Does MTLBlitCommandEncoder have implicit memory barriers?
I am working with untracked resources (MTLTexture) in iOS in Metal, so I must do all synchronisation manually.
I observe that an MTLBlitCommandEncoder (bce) does not have a barrier function:
"bce.memoryBarrier(resources: [myTexture])" does not exist, as it does e.g. on a MTLComputeCommandEncoder.
Is this because memory barriers are implicit?
Meaning if I have two copy calls in the same bce, like so
bce.copy... //copy1
bce.copy... //copy2
bce.endEncoding()

this is in fact
bce.copy... //copy1
....implicit barrier....
bce.copy... //copy2
bce.endEncoding()

So that there is no conflict if copy1 and copy2 write to overlapping memory areas?
I know I can put each copy in its own bce and put a fence in between to avoid a conflict, but this seems clunky.
An MTLComputeCommandEncoder has serial and concurrent options, and the barrier is obviously to help synchronize in the concurrent case as it is pointless for the serial case. Given that the barrier function does not exist for a MTLBlitCommandEncoder, I tend to think that this is all guaranteed to run serially anyway, so no conflicts among copy1 and copy2, but I am not sure...
Does someone know how it works for sure? Thank you!
